# convert a JSON to another w/ circe

Tags: json, scala, avro, circe

I would like to convert this JSON

```
{
    "l1k1": {
        "l2k1": "l2v1",
        "l2k2": 1
    },
    "l1k2": [
        {
            "e1l1": "e1v1",
            "e1l2": "e1v2"
        },
        {
            "e2l1": "e2v1",
            "e2l2": "e2v2"
        }
    ]
}
```

to this one

```
{
    "papa": {
        "l1k1c": {
            "l2k1c": {
                "string": "l2v1"
            },
            "l2k2c": {
                "int": 1
            }
        },
        "l1k2c": {
            "array": [
                {
                    "e1l1": "e1v1",
                    "e1l2": "e1v2"
                },
                {
                    "e2l1": "e2v1",
                    "e2l2": "e2v2"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

where:

- "l" stands for level
- "k" for key, "v" for value
- "e" for element
- "c" for copy (where "*" maps to "*c")

I'm using circe's [Json](https://circe.github.io/circe/api/io/circe/Json.html) but having a hard time renaming the keys or creating parents or children with it. As I'm writing this, I'm thinking I may need to use its [ACursor](https://circe.github.io/circe/api/io/circe/ACursor.html) instead. As you may have guessed, I'm trying to generate an AVRO doc from an input JSON. I'm open to help w/ my approach or any suggestions about how to go about it in a cleaner way.

Comment: Can you share what you've already tried?

Comment: I would suggest to create 2 case classes (that resembles first and second json), convert first class to second and then finally convert to JSON.